# flash builder crashes at startup

Tags: flash-builder

I have the following problem
WHen lunching FlashBuilder.exe (BURRITO): it crashes and creates an error log file such us: 
hs_err_pid7084.log and following

But when I munch FlashBuilderC.exe : it opens a CMD dos window and flash builder starts.
I tried to reinstall it : no way.

Can one help me ?
I found a solution removeing some .metadatas in Eclips or similar but I cannot find it any more

Regards

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 21):

It may be a little bit late for an answer, but you can try to do this:

### Step 1:

- Go to your User directory and navigate to your Flash Builder Files:

**FOR WINDOWS**:

> C:\Users\[YOUR USER] \Adobe Flash Builder
>   4.5\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\

**FOR OSX {FILES HIDDEN}**:

> [Flash Builder Workspace
>   Directory]\.metadata\org.eclipse.core.resources\

---

### Step 2:

- If there is a ".snap" file, delete it and then start "FlashBuilderC.exe" in Admin-Mode
  FOR WINDOWS BY DEFAULT:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\

---

### Step 3:

- Close Flash Builder again and then open Flash Builder normally (should work again)

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I found this article looking for a problem where FB was not crashing, but hanging on startup (OSX). Tried it on a lark, and what do you know, it worked! The problem seems to be related to switching branches in git, so I figured some cache file was to blame. Thanks!

Comment: Same here, fixed the problem on OSX, but file path was slightly different. I found the file at: `~/Documents/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap`.  
(the `.plugins` folder is different from the answer)

Comment: I was getting a hang on Flash Builder 4.7 startup. In my case, I had to go to the directory for the *workspace* I was trying to open and deleted the .snap file there. (This was under Windows 7).

Comment: Your `.metadata` directory might also have a `.lock` file - if this exists when flash builder starts it will refuse to use the workspace.

Comment: The given folder had no .snap file, i just deleted the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources folder, that fixed the problem

Answer (score 8):

I've had this problem a couple of times. For the first time, deleting the `.snap` file worked. Not the second time, however.

I looked at the log file for the workspace located under the `.metadata` folder (inside your Flash Builder files, typically: `c:\Users\[YOUR USER]\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\`), and found the following line towards the end:

> !MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs
>   should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown:

I solved this by deleting the file `workbench.xml` in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` folder under the `.plugins` one, and then starting up the Flash Builder again.

The workspace at least opened, admittedly with a problematic project but at least I could fix it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting:

> C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench

Comment: Link no longer works...  This solution isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, I usuall just delete the metadata from my workspace and the reimport all the existing projects to workspace.

Run the following inside your workspace:

```
$ rm -rf .metadata
```

Comment: Be careful doing this as you will loose all of you projects Try deleting the .snap file first.

Comment: You can then reimport then really easily. That doesn't delete any needed file IMO

Comment: Except all your preferences, key mappings, shortcuts, etc. This is the equivalent of creating a new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening often enough for me that I ended up writing a batch file to fix the issue, using Marchar and fenomas's posts - thanks guys! (Note - ensure the Flash Builder process has been killed before running it)

```
cd C:\Users\[your name here]\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\.metadata
del .lock

cd C:\Users\[your name here]\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
del .snap
```

Comment: when I try to do this the command prompt says 'Adobe is not recognized as an external or internal command, operable program or batch file.'?

Comment: What OS are you using Marnix? This worked fine on Windows 7 for me, but perhaps the space after Adobe in the commands is causing problems? (You could try putting double quotes around `"Adobe Flash Builder 4.7"` Or maybe you've got a stray carriage return in the command?

Answer (score 0):

[My eventual solution](http://www.howtodouggie.com/2012/04/how-to-make-flash-builder-start-when-it.html):

1. Rename the workspace folder.  [My default was at C:\Users\jhouser\Adobe Flash Builder 4]
2. Start up Flash Builder.  Behold!  It starts!  All the projects are now broken because the paths are now incorrect.
3. Shut down Flash Builder.
4. Rename the workspace folder back to what it was.
5. Start up Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience as Apollo M. Deleting the .snap and .lock files didn't work for me.

I located the workbench.xml file (C:\Users[your name here]\Documents[your project directory].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench) and deleted the individual entries under the "" tag.

Nice thing about this is that my workspace opened correctly, with no need to re-import my projects.